# Batch File - Replace Keyword in txt files

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, text, replace

i'm trying to make some BAT files that will scan all files with .txt extension, list them, and replace multiple keywords. I don't know what are txt files names.

Here is what i got:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a counter=1
set "SEARCH_A=KEYWORD1"
set "REPLACE_A=REPLACED1"
set "SEARCH_B=KEYWORD2"
set "REPLACE_B=REPLACED2"
set "newfile=Output.txt"

for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (

echo %%~nxi>> search_result.txt 

set "textfile=%%~nxi"
set "newfile=Output.txt"

(for /f "delims=" %%j in (!textfile!) do (
    set "line=%%j"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%SEARCH_A%=%REPLACE_A%!"
    set "line=!line:%SEARCH_B%=%REPLACE_B%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"

del !textfile!

rename %newfile%  !textfile!  

set /a counter=!counter!+1    


)

endlocal
```

And it kind of works. I have got two problems:

- keyword replacing doesn't work with TXT files that have two words in name with space between. Is there any way to fix that?
- it also checks files in directories that are levels down than .bat file. How to limit it to check only files in the same level as .bat?

Please help me. I'm a total noob btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose all file/foldernames that (may) contain spaces in quotes (better: get used to enclose *all* file/foldernames in quotes):

```
(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("!textfile!") do (
```

(`usebackq` is needed to actually process the textfile instead of just the string of it's name)

```
del "!textfile!"
rename "%newfile%"  "!textfile!"
```

`for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (`:  `/r` says "recursive" (including sub directories). Just skip the `/r` to process just the current folder without subfolders.

Comment: Wow! That works! Thank you very much! Can you maybe also let me know what would be the difference, it we could assume that there is only one TXT file in directory with BAT file? But the filename still is unknown, so would this assumption simplify the code at all?

Comment: no not really. You use `for %%I in (*.txt)` to get the needed filename. To simplify, you could use `%%~nxi` instead of `!textfile!`, but it's less readable.